# ¿Cómo ejecutar un programa cada cierto tiempo en java

Tags: java, java-8

Me gustaría que cada cierto tiempo se ejecutara un programa, por ejemplo cada 60 segundos.

El programa sería por ejemplo:

```
void hola_mundo() {
   System.out.println("Hola Mundo");
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? He leído por ahí que con **ScheduledExecutorService** y **Executors**, pero no se muy bien como implementarlo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Daniel. Has de intentar implementarlo y presentarnos lo que has probado y qué errores te ha dado. Busca la documentacion para que te ayude a implementarlo. Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, puedes usar la interfaz `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Te pongo aquí [lo que explica la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), traducido:

Un `ExecutorService` puede programar comandos para ejecutarse después de un retardo determinado, o para ejecutar periódicamente.

Los métodos de programación crean tareas con varios retrasos y devuelven un objeto de tarea que se puede utilizar para cancelar o comprobar la ejecución. Los métodos `scheduleAtFixedRate` y `scheduleWithFixedDelay` crean y ejecutan tareas que se ejecutan periódicamente hasta que se cancelan.

Los comandos enviados utilizando los métodos de envío `Executor.execute` (Runnable) y `ExecutorService` se programan con un retardo solicitado de cero. También se permiten los retardos cero y negativo (pero no los períodos) en los métodos de planificación y se tratan como solicitudes de ejecución inmediata.

Todos los métodos de programación aceptan demoras y períodos relativos como argumentos, no tiempos o fechas absolutos. Es una cuestión simple transformar un tiempo absoluto representado como una Fecha en el formulario requerido. Por ejemplo, para programar en una cierta fecha futura, puede utilizar: `schedule(task, date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`. Tenga en cuenta, sin embargo, que la expiración de un retardo relativo no tiene que coincidir con la fecha actual en la que se habilita la tarea debido a los protocolos de sincronización de la hora de la red, la deriva del reloj u otros factores.

La clase `Executors` proporciona métodos de fábrica convenientes para las implementaciones de `ScheduledExecutorService` proporcionadas en este paquete.

---

## Ejemplos

### Reproducir un beep e imprimir "ok" en pantalla cada minuto, con un retraso inicial de 1 minuto.

La fuente original de este programa [es esta](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/concurrency/java-concurrency-scheduling-tasks-to-execute-after-a-given-delay-or-periodically) (hay otros ejemplos en el enlace). Lo he modificado para adaptarlo a los requerimientos planteados en tu pregunta:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

/**
 *  * BeepClock.java  *  * This program demonstrates how to schedule a task to
 * execute after  * an initial delay, and repeat after a fixed rate.  *  
 *
 *
 * @author www.codejava.net  
 */
public class BeepClock implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ok");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler
                = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        Runnable task = new BeepClock();
        int initialDelay = 1;
        int periodicDelay = 1;
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, periodicDelay,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES
        );
    }
}
```

---

### Ejemplo de la documentación: Emite un beep cada 10 segundos durante una hora

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };
     final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Vale, perfecto me funciona así !! Ahora tengo otra duda ¿como podría hacer esto mismo a través de un script?

Comment: @DanielRuiz cuando dices:  _hacerlo a través de un script_ no comprendo bien a lo que te refieres. De todos modos, la duda inicial era lo que planteas en la pregunta. Subrayo que Stackoverflow funciona *por preguntas*, es normal que cuando uno resuelve un problema le vienen otras dudas, lo correcto es plantearlo en una **nueva pregunta**. Así se respeta el formato del sitio y se da la posibilidad de abordar el tema con más amplitud, además puedes obtener respuestas desde varios puntos de vista. Pero antes, verifica que una duda similar no haya sido ya resuelta aquí, usando el buscador.

Comment: Que mala odna esta comunidad que no vota las preguntas y respuestas que valen mucho la pena, como estas !!! Gracias, 1 año después, porque a mi me ayudó mucho hoy en día :)